# How do I tell boto operation was successful?

Tags: python, networking, amazon-s3, network-programming, boto

I'm doing fairy straightforward uploading with boto

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("data"):
    for file in files:
        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = file
        k.set_contents_from_filename(os.path.join(path,file))
```

but set_contents_from_filename does not return anything. How do I tell the operation was success and not failed silently? I'm using RiakCS as a backend if it is important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since all of the underlying service requests that boto makes are HTTP-based, boto monitors the status codes and raises a Python exception if the HTTP status code does not indicate success.  So, if it doesn't raise an exception it should be successful.

Comment: Does some kind of integrity checks happen during the process? As I understand HTTP does not do integrity checks (correct me if I'm wrong), it is up to the user/developer of application to do this.

Comment: In the case of the ``set_contents_from_*`` operations of S3, boto computes an MD5 checksum before sending the file.  It then sends that checksum as part of the upload so S3 can validate it on the server side.  It also compares the computed MD5 with the ETag header returned which, for single-part files, is always the MD5.